# Setting different default values for dropdownlist(MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have flights timetable - Schedule view with list of flights
 Where I just return View and have some filters and sorting.

Here is part of my view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<AirPortIS.Models.Flight>

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Flights</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="modDialog" class="modal fade">
        <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>
    </div> 

    <table class="table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Flight №</th>
                <th>Departure</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>@Html.ActionLink("Day", "Schedule", new { sort = ViewBag.SortDay, company = ViewBag.FiltrC, destination = ViewBag.FiltrD })</th>
                <th>Departure Time</th>
                <th>Arrival Time</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>@Html.ActionLink("Seats", "Schedule", new { sort = ViewBag.SortSeats, company = ViewBag.FiltrC, destination = ViewBag.FiltrD })</th>
                <th>@Html.ActionLink("Cost", "Schedule", new { sort = ViewBag.SortCost, company = ViewBag.FiltrC, destination = ViewBag.FiltrD })</th>
                <th>Book ticket</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var f in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(f.FlightId.ToString(), "FlightDetails", new { id = f.FlightId }, new {@class = "flItem" } )</td>
                <td>@f.Departure</td>
                <td>@f.Destination</td>
                <td>@f.Day</td>
                <td>@f.DepartureTime</td>
                <td>@f.ArrivalTime</td>
                <td>@f.Company.Name</td>
                <td>@f.Seats</td>
                <td>@f.Cost</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Link for booking ticket")</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

I need to do that by clicking on a button "Book ticket" user is getting a page where dropdownlist have a preset value of FlightId.
For example we have a flight №1 and a link "Book ticket",so when user goes the booking ticket page he gets a droptdownlist with preselected value "1"

Here is my ticket Model

```
public class Tickets
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public Flight Flight { get; set; }
    public string Seat {get;set; }
    public string Passenger { get; set; }
    public int Flightid { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

And part of TicketsController:

```
 public class TicketsController : Controller
{
    private readonly AirportContext _db = new AirportContext();
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Tickets()
    {
        var ticket = _db.Tickets.Include(t => t.Flight);
        return View(ticket);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BookTicket()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusList = new SelectList(new List<string> { "Book", "Buy" });
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> flights = new SelectList(_db.Flights.ToList(), "FlightId", "FlightId");
        ViewData["flights"] = flights;
        ViewData["statusList"] = statusList;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BookTicket(Tickets ticket)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusList = new SelectList(new List<string> { "Book", "Buy" });
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> flights = new SelectList(_db.Flights.ToList(), "FlightId", "FlightId");
        ViewData["flights"] = flights;
        ViewData["statusList"] = statusList;
        foreach (var c in _db.Tickets.ToList())
        {
            if ((_db.Tickets.ToList().Exists(x => c.TicketId == ticket.TicketId)) || (ticket.TicketId <= 0))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("TicketId", "Wrong ticket id");
            }
            if ((_db.Tickets.ToList().Exists(x => c.Seat == ticket.Seat)) && (_db.Tickets.ToList().Exists(x => c.Flightid == ticket.Flightid))
                && (_db.Tickets.ToList().Exists(x => c.TicketId == ticket.TicketId)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Seat", "The seat is unavailable");
            }
            if (_db.Tickets.ToList().Exists(x => c.Passenger == ticket.Passenger))
            {
               ModelState.AddModelError("Passenger", "The ticket has already bought");
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Tickets");
        }
        else return View(ticket);
    }
```

And my BookTikcet View:

```
@model AirPortIS.Models.Tickets

@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Book ticket";
}
<h2>Book ticket:</h2>

<form class="form-inline" method="post">
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        Ticket №<br/>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.TicketId)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
       Flight №<br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Flightid, ViewData["flights"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        Место<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Seat)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        Passenger Name<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Passenger)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        Status<br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Status, ViewData["statusList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
    </div>
        <div>
            <input class="btn-success" type="submit" value="Book Ticket"/>
        </div>
</form>


<div>
<form method="get" action="Tickets">
    <button class="btn-danger" type="submit">Cancel</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to do it,so this whole code above just a standart code for creating  a new ticket.
How I should modify code or add something to have this (For example we have a flight №1 and a link "Book ticket",so when user goes the booking ticket page he gets a droptdownlist with preselected value "1",for flight №2 on a page dropdownlist has a preselected value "2" for FlightId.
Hope that my question is clear,sorry if something is wrong written or not quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `FlightId` as a route (or query string) value to the `BookTicket` method. You link should be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book ticket", "BookTicket", new { id = f.FlightId })
```

and modify the method to

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BookTicket(int ID)
{
    ... // set you SelectLists as above
    // Initialize your model and set the Flightid property
    var model = new Tickets()
    {
        Flightid = ID
    };
    return View(model); // return the model to the view
}
```

Your dropdownlist will now have the option identified by Flightid selected when you first generate the view.

Note. I recommend you use a view model rather than your `Tickets` data model which will contain properties `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Flights` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList` rather than using `ViewData` so that your view are strongly typed using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Flightid, Model.Flights)
```

You should also consider refactoring the code to populate the `SelectLists` into a private method so that you do not repeat code, for example

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
{
    model.Flights = new SelectList(...);
    model.StatusList = new SelectList(...);
}
```

Note also that it is a waste of resources to be calling your database to get the `SelectList`'s in the POST method if `ModelState` is valid. Your code should be

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     ConfigureViewModel(model); // only necessary if you need to return the view
     return View(model);
}
// save and redirect
```

Side note: It's unclear why you actually need a dropdownlist for `Flightid` in the `BookTicket` view. The user has already selected the flight so why are you giving the option to change it? It might be more appropriate to just render the `Flightid` as a hidden or readonly input so its submitted back to the POST method.

Comment: Thank you for your good and clear answer.I will try it in a few minutes.I use dropdownlist because user might buy tickets not by certain flight(timetable page),but in general,where user can choose the flight